# Looping through columns and create a conditional column

Tags: powerquery

I had a comma separated long string that I have split into 17 columns. I want to get all the data where example SSD is part of the text. I have now created a conditional if statement with text.contains, so that if it contains the text then it will take all in that columns to the new one.

Like this:

```
each if Text.Contains([Column 1],"SSD") then [Column 1] 
else if Text.Contains([Column 2],"SSD") then [Column 2]
```

My question is if I can loop this text.Contains through all of the columns without writing the same with 17 if statements?

Write conditional text.contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, there's no reason to split the comma separated values into columns, thats just adding steps

```
Find =  Table.AddColumn(#"PriorStepNameHere", "SSD", each Text.Combine(List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform(Text.Split([ColumnNameToSearchHere],","),  each  if Text.Contains(_,"SSD") then _ else null)),","))
```

But if you have columns, you can check every column

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Text.Combine(List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform(Record.ToList(_),  each  if Text.Contains(_,"SSD") then _ else null)),","))
in  #"Added Custom"
```

Or check just specified columns

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Columns=Table.ColumnNames(Source),
Index = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source,"Index",0,1),
Find = Table.AddColumn(Index, "SSD", each Text.Combine(List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform(Record.ToList( Table.SelectColumns(Index,Columns){[Index]}),  each  if Text.Contains(_,"SSD") then _ else null)),","))
in Find
```

[image]

Comment: Thank, the first solution will work great. Just so I understand it, so it transforms the column to a list where it separates by comma for then to search for a word.

Comment: The column is already a list to which it applies a Text.Contains for each item. Remove the nulls and recombine with commas